# scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n") in java

Tags: java, split, delimiter

I have a simple code to understand which reads a file (`input2.txt`) and displays it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args )  throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]) );
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n");   
    String[] grid = scanner.next().split("\n");
    scanner.close();

    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length(); col++) {
            System.out.print(grid[row].charAt(col) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  } 
}
```

2. `input.txt` is

[image]

3. java Test `input.txt` is

[image]

What I don't understand is

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n");
```

Why does it use two `"\n\n"` instead of one `"\n"`?
FYI, If I use `scanner.useDelimiter("\n");` 
it doesn't work properly. This just read the first line from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Your file contains newlines (`\n`) so setting delimiter to a single newline will cause `next()` to return the first line.

Since your files doesn't contain any blank lines, i.e. has no double newlines, `next()` will return the first token, which is the entire file content.

As to why someone chose `\n\n`? Who knows.

Also be aware that this won't work on Windows, where lines are separated by `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the delimiter to `\n\n` will cause `scanner.next()` to return the entire file as one string, since there are no double new lines found. Setting the delimiter to anything that is never found would give the same behavior.

Next that string is split using `split("\n")` and the array will contain one entry per row from the file.

This can be written more cleanly like this

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String row = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int col = 0; col < row.length(); col++) {
            System.out.print(row.charAt(col) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using `split` with a `Scanner`. The second makes what the first should.

Instead, use `\n` as a delimiter for your `Scanner`, but since you are using `next()`, this means you should **iterate on the `Scanner`** until there are no more to scan for.

The `split` is really making you lose all the interest of using a `Scanner`. You are just reading the whole file once and splitting it when it's all in-memory. This could cause memory exceptions with large files.

Untested but something like this should work:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args )  throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]) );
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");   

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String row = scanner.next();

        for(int col = 0; col < row.length(); col++) {
            System.out.print(row.charAt(col) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    scanner.close();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :** You use `scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n");`
"\n\n" is a delimiter which was not found in the file so the first scanner.next() will give you the whole file !

And when you use .split("\n") on the whole file it will give you a array of elements found in the file splitted by "\n" this somehow made you think that your code is working.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args )  throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]) );
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n\n");   
    String[] grid = scanner.next().split("\n");
    scanner.close();

    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length(); col++) {
            System.out.print(grid[row].charAt(col) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  } 
}
```

**Case 2:** When you use `scanner.useDelimiter("\n")` scanner.next() returns you the first line as scanner has found a delimiter and is giving you the data line by line.

Now when you use `scanner.next().split("\n");` the regex "\n" didn't match and again you got back the whole String that is the first row,which made you think your code isn't working.

If you want to read the file you should use `scanner.hasNext()` in a while loop as specified in some answer already.

Comment: Is there any use case justifying the case 1? A buffered reading might do the trick. Plus the potential memory problems with large files.

Comment: Yup i don't know why op did it, probably was running someone else's code for learning.

Answer (score -1):

By using the delimiter '\n\n' you tell the scanner to split tokens there. My assumption is that the input file is a Uninx style file (so line break is \n) which has two line breaks at the end or an empty line somewhere.

So the scanner.next() will basically return you a sting token up the the end (or empty line) and then splitt that by by line.

So a better way to do this would probably be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]) );
scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
List<String> grid = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    grid(scanner.next());
}   
scanner.close();
```

Your code will only handle the content of the file up to the point where there are two '\n\n'.

Comment: If input is `Hello\n\nWorld`, you will get tokens `"Hello"`, `""`, and `"World"`. It doesn't stop at `\n\n`.

Comment: That is correct. My proposal works fine for the case where '\n\n' only occurs at the end of the file and not somewhere in the middle.